# gcc /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lncurses

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu, ncurses

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm currently working on a project involving C, OpenGL, a teapot and input methods.

The problem started when I decided to have arrow keys as input. I checked to see the key codes for arrow keys but all of the arrows return 0. I looked up how to get this to work and I found conio.h. Unfortunately, it is an old DOS header that is not available for Linux. Then I found a substitute called ncurses.

After installing the necessary libraries, by following the build instructions closely, I #included curses.h in my main.c source. When I first tried to compile using gcc, I got the following errors:

```
main.o:main.c:function _Key: error: undefined reference to 'stdscr'
main.o:main.c:function _Key: error: undefined reference to 'wgetch'
main.o:main.c:function _Key: error: undefined reference to 'stdscr'
main.o:main.c:function _Key: error: undefined reference to 'wgetch'
```

I found a fix by adding -lncurses to the makefile like so:

```
SOURCES=main.c

main: main.o
    gcc -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lncurses main.o -o main

main.o: main.c
    gcc -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -c main.c
```

But I was greeted by another error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lncurses
```

As well as the previous errors.

I have spent the last 2 days searching both the Ubuntu forums and StackOverFlow. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I don't know if this is important but when I try to run /usr/bin/ld I get this error:

```
ld: fatal error: no input files
```

Comment: `apt-get install libncurses5-dev`?

Comment: why do these comments have to be so small -_-
I didn't see your comment before but that was the fix. Dunno why but it seems I installed some kind of un-official version that the compiler didn't recognize. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 51):

For anyone with the same problem I had: I was missing the 32 bit libraries; I was compiling 32 bit on a 64 bit server which was missing the lib32ncurses5-dev package.

On Ubuntu I simply ran:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev
```

Comment: I couldn't install gnureadline via pip, python 2.7 and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should put the libraries *after* the object file when linking. And not have them at all in the compilation of of the source file.

After that, if ncurses is not installed in a standard search folder you need to point out to the linker where it is, this is done with the `-L` command line option:

```
gcc main.o -o main -L/location/of/ncurses -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lncurses
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the `ncurses-static` package too, if you have only the `ncurses-devel` package installed in your Ubuntu OS.

If that solves your problem, plus if you add @Joachim's compiling instructions, you are off to a great start.

```
gcc main.o -o main -L/location/of/ncurses -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lncurses
```

The linker can't find your shared library in it's search path. If you add the directory where your shared lib is to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable the linker should find it and be able to link against it. In that case you could omit the `-L` option to gcc:

```
gcc main.o -o main -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lncurses
```

And it should compile fine.

EDIT:
Good to know that `apt-get install libncurses5-dev` fixes your problem.

FYI.
The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable contains a colon separated list of paths that the linker uses to resolve library dependencies at run time. These paths will be given priority over the standard library paths `/lib` and `/usr/lib`. The standard paths will still be searched, but only after the list of paths in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has been exhausted.

The best way to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is to set it on the command line or script immediately before executing the program. This way you can keep the new `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isolated from the rest of your system i.e. local to the current running running instance of shell.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/libncurses/library/directory/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
$ gcc main.o -o main -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lncurses
```

Comment: More problems still :/
1. I have only libncurses.so.5 and libncurses.so.5.9 both of which are not reconginzed

2. Where does one find the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

Comment: You don't want to use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`; if you need to configure non-standard loader paths then create a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I looked at the files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and the ncurses libraries are in those directories:
lib/i386-linux-gnu and usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu