# How can I use kbhit() and getch() on Linux? C++

Tags: c++, input, getch, kbhit

I'm wrinig a simple snake game on C++. But I have a problem: I need to use `kbhit()` and `getch()` for read what the user enters. For use it I need `conio.h` but there're no this library on Linux. I tryed use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux), but there're have a trouble: code is compiling but I can't use program, it just stoping.

So how can I use `kbhit()` and `getch()`? Or is there any alternative for it?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

bool GameOver;
const int height = 20;
const int width = 20;
int x, y, fruit_x, fruit_y, score;
enum eDirection { STOP, RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;

void setup() {
    GameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width / 2 - 1;
    y = height / 2 - 1;
    fruit_x = rand() % width;
    fruit_y = rand() % height;
    score = 0;
}

void draw() {
    system("clear");

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == width - 1)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        if (i == y && j == x)
        {
            cout << "0";
        }
        else if (i == fruit_y && j == fruit_x)
        {
            cout << "F";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void input() {
    if (_kbhit)
    {
        switch(getch())
    {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            GameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void logic() {
    switch(dir)
    {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }
}


int main() {
    setup();
    while(!GameOver)
    {
        draw();
        input();
        logic();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html).

Comment: game.cpp:63:6: error: ‘kbhit’ was not declared in this scope. There're no kbhit() and getch()

Comment: Correct, the API to ncurses is different from the API for conio.  You'll need to read the documentation for ncurses.

Comment: So, I tried to use this. I should make while(true) for for read what the user enters, but it's stops my code

Comment: Did you turn on no-delay mode, as mentioned in the [getch](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) documentation?

Comment: So, I'm using while (true) { switch(getch()) {...} }. And get /tmp/ccDiCfGP.o: In function `input()':
game.cpp:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `stdscr'
game.cpp:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `wgetch'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you install the ncurses library ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416487/gcc-usr-bin-ld-error-cannot-find-lncurses))?  Are you linking to the ncurses library?  Have you gotten an [example](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-install-ncurses-library-headers-on-debian-ubuntu-centos-fedora/) ncurses program to work?

Comment: Yes I have installed and linked the library. I watched the example and worked with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [zoelabbb](https://github.com/zoelabbb) said in this [link](https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h),

Step 1 :
Open terminal sudo apt-get update

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h.git
cd conio.h
```

Step 2 :

```
sudo cp conio.h /usr/include/
```

**or** (step 2)

In GUI, using  `open-as-administrator` pakage:

```
Copy file conio.h --> !! copy file not folder !!
Go to /usr/include/
Right click on folder /usr/include/
Choose Open as Administrator
Paste file conio.h
```

**Finaly** after *step 1* and *step 2* you can use `#include <conio.h>` in your code.