# Cannot Install packages in python, Error Building wheel for readline (setup.py)

Tags: python, linux

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, I also have python 2.7 and python 3.8.5 installed on my machine. I tried to install requirements.txt with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` and got me the following error.

Is this because I have conflict on my python installed on my computer?

p.s the error is too long, so I post it [here](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4vi)

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416487/gcc-usr-bin-ld-error-cannot-find-lncurses

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87 Thank you man that's work!